# Sending Data From One Screen To Another in App Inventor 2

Tags: android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0Fep.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnY3p.png)So I'm working on an app where when the user clicks a title in a list picker, another screen opens and the picture of the place is shown. I've been looking around and I can't figure out how to send the data from one screen to another along with the data of a picture. I've seen the use of Tinydb, but I'm honestly very confused about it. I'm using MIT App Inventor 2 btw. I've included images to help with my confusion

Comment: You can send data by intent...
Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application)...

Answer (score 0):

1. Using Static Variable :

   - If the `title` data is static then you can define it as static so that way it will be the same copy for all the objects of `Screen1`.
   - Now you can access it from `Screen2` by saying Screen1.title
2. Using intents to communincate

   - If the title is a data that can be passed via an `intent` that use to pass the title
   - For example if title is a string  from **Screen1** `intent.putExtra("TITLE", title);`
   - In **Screen2** you can do the following

     ```
     String newString;
     if (savedInstanceState == null) {
          Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
          if(extras == null) {
              newString= null;
          } 
          else {
               newString= extras.getString("TITLE");
          } 
     } 
     else {
               newString=(String)savedInstanceState.getSerializable("TITLE");
     }
     ```
3. Using interfaces for callbacks:

   - If the `title` is really that important you can pass an interface to `Screen2` and let `Screen1` class implement this interface
   - Have a reference to `Screen1` class interface
   - access the `title` by making a callback to this class of `Screen1`
4. Having Direct reference to Screen1 class:

   - Let `Screen2` have a direct reference to that particular object of `Screen1` class that contains the title
   - That way `Screen2` can access the attributes of `Screen1` class
   - Remember when having a direct reference you want the same object of `Screen1` to be passed you can do this by using `this` keyword

Answer (score 0):

Passing Data Through `Intent()` is the Best way for passing data to another activity or fragment.and it is very easy to use.
Refer This [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application)

Comment: So I understand most of the actual code that is going on with the intent, but I'm utterly confused on how to put that into the block formation which is forced upon the user in App Inventor. If you could provide any other feedback, that would be great.